# segmentation fault and memory not mapped when loading the rtracklayer package from Bioconductor into R in a conda environment

Tags: r, conda, bioconductor

I have create a conda environment with r and bioconductor-rtracklayer in it:

`conda create --name bioconductor-rtracklayer --channel conda-forge --channel bioconda --channel r --yes r=3.5.1 bioconductor-rtracklayer=1.42.1`

and activated it:

`conda activate bioconductor-rtracklayer`

I am working on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

I then open R in the terminal and type:

`library(rtracklayer)`

and get the following error:

```
Loading required package: GenomicRanges
Loading required package: stats4
Loading required package: BiocGenerics
Loading required package: parallel

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:parallel’:

    clusterApply, clusterApplyLB, clusterCall, clusterEvalQ,
    clusterExport, clusterMap, parApply, parCapply, parLapply,
    parLapplyLB, parRapply, parSapply, parSapplyLB

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    anyDuplicated, append, as.data.frame, basename, cbind, colMeans,
    colnames, colSums, dirname, do.call, duplicated, eval, evalq,
    Filter, Find, get, grep, grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply,
    lengths, Map, mapply, match, mget, order, paste, pmax, pmax.int,
    pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank, rbind, Reduce, rowMeans, rownames,
    rowSums, sapply, setdiff, sort, table, tapply, union, unique,
    unsplit, which, which.max, which.min

Loading required package: S4Vectors

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
 8: library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc,     quietly = quietly)
 9: .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
10: library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc,     quietly = quietly)
11: .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
12: library(rtracklayer)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Can please someone help me?

Note that I can run `library(rtracklayer)` from within RStudio without any problems and I can use the functions in the package successfully. Why is there this discrepancy between the command line and RStudio?

#### Following Johannes Koester's comment, I have created a conda environment and installed bioconductor-rtracklayer without specifying the r channel:

```
conda create --name bioconductor-rtracklayer --channel conda-forge --channel bioconda --yes r=3.5.1 bioconductor-rtracklayer=1.42.1
```

activate the environment, opened R in the terminal and typed `library(rtracklayer)` but I still got the following error:

```
Loading required package: GenomicRanges
Loading required package: stats4
Loading required package: BiocGenerics
Loading required package: parallel

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:parallel’:

    clusterApply, clusterApplyLB, clusterCall, clusterEvalQ,
    clusterExport, clusterMap, parApply, parCapply, parLapply,
    parLapplyLB, parRapply, parSapply, parSapplyLB

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    anyDuplicated, append, as.data.frame, basename, cbind, colMeans,
    colnames, colSums, dirname, do.call, duplicated, eval, evalq,
    Filter, Find, get, grep, grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply,
    lengths, Map, mapply, match, mget, order, paste, pmax, pmax.int,
    pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank, rbind, Reduce, rowMeans, rownames,
    rowSums, sapply, setdiff, sort, table, tapply, union, unique,
    unsplit, which, which.max, which.min

Loading required package: S4Vectors

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
 8: library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc,     quietly = quietly)
 9: .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
10: library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc,     quietly = quietly)
11: .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
12: library(rtracklayer)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection: 1
R is aborting now ...
[1]    44550 segmentation fault  R
```

Note that my .libPaths() contains:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/Users/user/Library/R/3.5/library"
[2] "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/bioconductor-rtracklayer/lib/R/library"
```

should I remove the first line that is inside `.libPaths()` for R to fetch the R package in the conda environment?

However, `library(rtracklayer, lib.loc = '/Users/user/anaconda/envs/bioconductor-rtracklayer/lib/R/library')` gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went into .bash_profile and deleted the R_LIBS_USER variable. It's now working. Suggested by Johannes Koester.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to mix the r channel with conda forge and bioconda. They are even binary incompatible. All packages from the r channel are in conda-forge now. Please see http://bioconda.github.io for the right channel order and combination. Hope that this might solve the error already.